# OpenOCD SWO output from an STM32F4 and buffering

Tags: stm32f4, openocd

In an STM32F4-based system I am using SWO for my trace output (intercepting `_write()` to use `ITM_SendChar()` in the usual way).  I can view the SWO output faultlessly in ST's [Eclipse-based] Cube IDE with the SWO clock at 2 MHz (core clock 168 MHz); never a single problem.  However I need a stream I can read for CI purposes and have been employing OpenOCD [0.10.0+dev-01193-g5ce997d (2020-02-20)], which ST supplies inside its toolchain, with ST's provided setup scripts, to do that.

This *mostly* works fine, except about 50% of the time OpenOCD does not write-out the end of the trace output.  This is with exactly the same target HW/SW as I use with the Cube IDE, so it must be a PC-side-tools thing rather than a target HW/SW issue.  It *looks* like a buffering problem so I have also tried getting OpenOCD to export the SWO stream through its TCL server port instead of writing it to a file but that behaves in exactly the same way.

The target HW/SW is not crashing, I can see from a flashed LED that it has executed to completion, and the standard `ITM_SendChar()` implementation (from the CMSIS headers) blocks on a register value until the character has been sent so nothing can be missed from a target-SW perspective.  Yet somehow the end has fallen off.

Has anyone else seen this or have any advice on the topic?

I am invoking OpenOCD with parameters:

```
-c "init" -c "itm port 0 on" -c "tpiu config internal swo.dat uart off 168000000 2000000" -c "reset init" -c "resume"
```

...and of course pointing it at ST's STM32F4 configuration and interface files.

This is all on Windows 10, in case it matters.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I figured out how to use the ST-Link GDB server, the one which the STM32Cube IDE uses under the hood, for this instead, as that doesn't show the problem.  However in case anyone else has this issue, here is some advice I received from someone who is using OpenOCD successfully for SWO capture with an STM32F7 platform:

> 1. I use the latest xpack version of openocd (the ST Cube IDE supplied versions of openocd and gcc is quite dated and many issues have been
>    corrected since their original release).
> 2. I've had to add gdb events to my .cfg file to force the itm port to initialize and flush consistently ... using the folllowing:
>
> ```
> $_TARGETNAME configure -event gdb-detach { itm port 0 off; itm port 1
> off; reset; shutdown }
> $_TARGETNAME configure -event gdb-attach
> {adapter_khz 4000; itm port 0 on; itm port 1 on}
> ```